# @ionic-native/aes-256 not working for iOS platform

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, encryption, aes

I have Installed the following plugins into my Ionic 3 Project :-

1. cordova-plugin-aes256-encryption
2. @ionic-native/aes-256

trying to execute below code but found it's not working on my iOS device

```
import { AES256 } from "@ionic-native/aes-256";
constructor(private aes256: AES256){}
this.aes256.encrypt(
                this.secureKey,
                this.secureIV,
                JSON.stringify(dataObject)
              )
              .then(res => {
                console.log("Encrypted Data:======> ", res);
                this.result= res; // it's not giving the encrypted output 
              })
              .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
```

Comment: It's working on Android device ?

Comment: yes it is working fine on android platform

Comment: Strange. try wrapp your code in `this.platform.ready().then(() => your code)`

Comment: i tried this but this is not helping at all

Comment: `constructor(private aes256: AES256) {
   this.generateSecureKeyAndIV();
}`
And this in your constructor ?

Comment: actually i am not using this method generateSecureKeyAndIV() i have hardcoded values in my code that's i am using as key and iv

Comment: Strange. Open an issue in github repository